# Linking Id's through a Macro in Access

Tags: ms-access, macros

I'm trying to make a relation between two tables to show information through a Macro. To give a perspective, I have a table called 'Companies' where there are all the information needed. I've made a 'Home' form where there is a SubForm to show the companies.

My idea is that the field 'Companies' of this subform, which shows the name of the company, could link to another subform called 'Companies Detail' through the ID.

So far, I've done this to the macro (the id field is called Id_company).:
The syntaxis is in spanish so sorry for that and hope this could be understable:

`If EsNulo([Formularios]![Consulta para Detalle Empresas]![Id_company])` then do a BIP.

`If NoEs EsNulo([Formularios]![Consulta para Detalle Empresas]![Id_company])` then `OpenForm`

and in the conditions on `WHERE` I've written: `="[Id]=" & [Id_company]`

The idea is that when you click on the name of the company in the Home form, this redirects to the 'Consulta para Detalle Empresas' form. I can't get it working. I'd like to hear opinions and I'll share more information and do my best to make it understandable if it isn't at all. Thank you in advance.

Edit: Finally it seems that I've been able to link both forms, but I have a question:

when I first click to a company to get redirect to 'Company Detail' it says something like: The form isn't open or doesn't exist in the database. If I open the form, than it works. That means I need to have the form pre-opened? I guess there's something I'm missing, so how can I refer to that form without opening it before?

Also, I get the links in the event 'OnClick' right, but I'd like them to appear as an hyperlink (just as Northwind example). It works now (except for that I've just mentioned) but I'd like the company names to appear like an hyperlink. How should I do it? Here's an image of the error message, sorry because it is in spanish.

[image]

Comment: What does " I can't get it working." mean? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried to run the code I've written before. More or less, what I want to get done is similar to what there is in the Northwind sample database, I'd like to have the links in the main form that correspond to specific companies by its id.

Comment: That doesn't help. If you have something you can show us, perhaps we can help you fix it. "more or less" is not a debugging technique. You may not be able to provide a working example that reproduces the problem, but you need to demonstrate what you've already tried, where the error happens, and how you tried to fix it.

Comment: Thank you again for your comment. I've edited the first post. I've successfully linked the forms the way I wanted, but it appears this strange error message. Any thoughts on that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Cross-posted http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=67114